# Play audio when splash screen start

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

there is a method to play a music when the splash screen is run?
this is my splash screen code:

```
// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT= 2000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {



        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start   main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MyActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close  activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

I created the raw folder in res / raw and put in my song, how can I play it when the run splash screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use,

```
myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.loveme);
    if (myMediaPlayer != null) {
            myMediaPlayer.start();
        } else {
            myMediaPlayer.reset();
            try {
                myMediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            myMediaPlayer.start();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(xxx.this, R.raw.xxx);
```